# Is it possible that my connection speed could effect my FPS?

Tags: hardware, smite

Recently I got my laptop repaired. I started it up, updated drivers and started up smite. However, when I began playing I noticed my FPS was low, even in the menu. It told me my FPS was 15.32 my ping was 132 and the number under that was 45. The other number is usually around 6 on other laptops. Is this 3rd factor stopping me from playing at an average frame rate?

Comment: just wanted to mention, Smite is like an EA game, where you log in to HiRes servers whenever you start the game, not just when you enter matchmaking. This could mean intermittent behavior, even in the menus, if your connection to their server isnt solid. It could be analogized to a website thats static, which loads once and is done, or a site that continuously updates a news crawler on the page; if that crawler lags, it could be you, the server, maybe a hiccup in the login process... Its not out of the realm of possibility that lag could look like an FPS issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection speed isn't directly connected to FPS usually. Most likely, connection speed would cause for lag in player movement, events, and other things that happen online to everyone. An example would be if TNT goes off on a minecraft server, if you have a bad connection, you might not see it for a few seconds or you might get kicked all together. Hardware and resources of your PC is what affects FPS.

Answer (score 0):

> Depending on your laptops Plasma/LED/LCD screen resolution which works
>   with your video/graphic driver/card to project the image onto the
>   screen.. In essence, your internet connection doesn't have a barring
>   on the FPS. However.. a slow/laggy/chop connection can mask or project
>   something similar to an FPS issue.

Found that on a similar question. I don't know if it helps, but internet connection speeds don't affect you FPS, especially heavily. But again as said above.